# Составить определенную сумму из рандомного набора чисел (из набора юнитов, создать рандомную армию определенной мощности)

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть набор юнитов. Необходимо создать армию определенной мощности из рандомного количества стеков рандомных юнитов. Сила армии = силе ее стеков. Сила стека = сила юнита * на их количество.

```
const units = [
  { name: 'kent', hp: 10 },
  { name: 'gnom', hp: 20 },
  { name: 'elf', hp: 15 },
  { name: 'pegas', hp: 25 },
  { name: 'dendr', hp: 65 },
  { name: 'unicorn', hp: 85 },
  { name: 'dragon', hp: 150 },
];
```

Условия:

1. Каждый стек - один тип юнита;
2. Армия может состоять из не более, чем 7 стеков;
3. В армии не может быть 2 стека с одинаковыми юнитами;
4. Итоговая мощность армии может быть +- самый сильный юнит от выбранной.

П.С.: по сути, мощность армии, тоже рандомная. Просто берется из определенного диапазона.

Comment: Переформулируйте задачу - "Составить определенную сумму из рандомного набора чисел". То что это юниты, армия, сила и количества юнитов в стеке - для решения задачи не так важно (разве что вы разрешите складывать стеки).

Comment: @Kromster, как-то сложно звучит. Если бы я искал решение этой задачи... я бы вряд ли нашел ответ по такому заголовку... Просто дополнил

Comment: Тут еще не сказано про то, что такое `армия определенной мощности`. Если я скажу "создай мне армию мощностью 1111", сможет ли система это сделать? (Уточнение: с таким набором юнитов невозможно создать армию с именно такой мощностью). Если да, то по какому принципу? Ближайшее минимальное?

Comment: А насколько вам кстати важно условие "из рандомного количества стеков рандомных юнитов"? Почему бы просто не выбирать рандомом из пары сильных юнитов 1/2 мощности, 2/5 из средних, и не добирать слабыми до требуемой?

Comment: @Kromster, это разве не задача о рюкзаке? или там о размене монет?

Comment: @Grundy примерно к этому я и хотел подвести ТС, но имхо часть про рандомный набор стеков тут несколько лишняя, и ее можно "отбросить" в пользу более простого алгоритма. Если только знать какую X-Y проблему ТС решает изначально.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, Мощность армии может быть +- самый сильный юнит от выбранной. Дополнил вопрос пунктом 4

Comment: @Kromster, условия про рандомноность самое основное). Никакой другой проблемы нет - нужно создать рандомную армию

Answer (score 2):

Моя реализация:

Определяю силу армии. Определяю кол-во стеков и типаж юнитов, которое будет в ней. Потом, в цикле, беру рандомного юнита, вычитаю его силу из силы армии , пока сила армии не станет 0. Смущает кол-во итераций, которое необходимо сделать.

```js
const units = [
  { name: 'kent', hp: 10 },
  { name: 'gnom', hp: 20 },
  { name: 'elf', hp: 15 },
  { name: 'pegas', hp: 25 },
  { name: 'dendr', hp: 65 },
  { name: 'unicorn', hp: 85 },
  { name: 'dragon', hp: 150 },
];

const range_stack = [1, 7];
const stack_count = getRandom(range_stack[0], range_stack[1]);
const range_army_power = [10000, 15000];
let power_army = getRandom(range_army_power[0], range_army_power[1]);
const stack_units = getUnits(stack_count, units, getRandom);

let result = {};
let count = 0;
if (stack_units.length >1){
  while (power_army > 0) {
    const i = getRandom(stack_units.length - 1);
    const unit = units[i];
    const { name, hp } = unit;
    if (!result[name]) {
      result[name] = 0;
    }
    result[name]++;
    power_army -= hp;
    count++;
  }
} else {
  const { name, hp } = stack_units[0];
  result[name] = Math.floor(power_army/hp);
}
console.log(`Количество итераций: ${count}`);
console.log(result);

function getUnits(sum, units, getRandom) {
  const allUnits = units.map(i => i);
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
    const num = getRandom(allUnits.length - 1);
    const d = allUnits.splice(num, 1);
    result.push(d[0]);
  }
  return result;
}

function getRandom(min, max = false) {
  if (!min) {
    return Math.random();
  }
  if (max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * ++min);
}
```

Comment: А чем вас собственно смущает число итераций? Любой проц это выполнит за наносекунды.

Comment: Просто у меня есть ощущение, что задачу можно решить с намного меньшим кол-вом итерацией, если использовать другой подход

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы просто не набирать рандомом из пары сильных юнитов 1/2 мощности, 1/3 из средних, и не добирать слабыми до требуемой?

То есть алгоритм типа:

```
Ид = 4 + Рандом(2) // Получаем индекс сильного юнита
РазмерСтека = Мощность / 2 div Юниты[Ид].хп // Получаем размер стека сильных юнитов, не более половины всего
Добавить стек в армию
Мощность = Мощность - РазмерСтека * Юниты[Ид].хп

Ид = 1 + Рандом(3) // Получаем индекс среднего юнита
РазмерСтека = Мощность / 1.5 div Юниты[Ид].хп // Получаем размер стека средних юнитов не более 2/3 остатка
Добавить стек в армию
Мощность = Мощность - РазмерСтека * Юниты[Ид].хп

Ид = Рандом(2) // Получаем индекс слабого юнита
РазмерСтека = Мощность div Юниты[Ид].хп // Получаем размер стека слабых юнитов
Добавить стек в армию
```

По вкусу, сделать не 3, а 4-5 шагов с перекрытием диапазонов, шанс невключения любой группы кроме слабых, и т.п.

Comment: почему-то, мне кажтеся, что при таком подходе, теряется рандомность состава армии...., точнее, она станочится менее рандомной, чем, например, в моем варианте

Answer (score 0):

> Армия может состоять из не более, чем 7 стеков

В вопросе их всего 7, так что с этим можно ничего не делать. Но если всего вариантов больше, то надо сначала выбрать 7 случайных стеков.

> Мощность армии может быть +- самый сильный юнит от выбранной

Выбираем случайный юнит из доступных стеков до тех пор, пока мощность не станет больше заданной. Меньше делать смысла нет, поскольку диапазона достаточно в одну сторону. Что касается равных - можно и так, и так, но при равенстве вероятность получить максимум 1/7, а минимум 7/7 - поэтому я бы взял ещё один юнит для некого уравнивания шансов.

Comment: Ну.. выглядит так же как и в моем варианте. При таком подходе, меня смущает кол-во итераций, которые нужно сделать

Comment: @Дмытрык, я просто не читал... Про итерации - равно числу юнитов. Т. к. он армию набирает, ему же потом ею ещё и управлять на каждом шаге, такое число итераций смущать не должно.

Comment: Вот мысль пришла - идеально было бы, что бы кол-во итераций было равно кол-ву стеков. Нужно подумать, как это сделать

Comment: @Дмытрык, ну в идеале да, но реально смысла нет, потому что управление всё равно будет требовать цикла по всем юнитам. Да и подозреваю, что создание каждого юнита предполагает вызов `new SomeUnit(...)`, так что всё равно не сэкономишь. А ответ твой глянул, плюсанул)